# ondblclick all the images get deleted jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble deleting one image at a time. When I double click, all the images get deleted at the same time. How can I prevent this from happening? here is my script

```js
$(".bananas").on('dblclick', function(e) {
    var whichtr = $(this).closest("div");
    whichtr.remove();      
});
```

```js
$('img').on('click', function() {
  $('#fotos').append('<div class="imgdrag"><img class="modal-content" src="' + $(this).attr('src') + '"/></div>');
  $('.imgdrag').draggable();
  $('#fotos').droppable();
  $('.modal-content').resizable();
  $(".download").attr("href", $(this).attr('src'));
  $(".download").show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fotos" class="bananas">
  <img class="modal-content" id="imgdisplay" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-640-480-8.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Add whole code or at least html.

Comment: You remove the container. Perhaps you mean `$(".bananas").on('dblclick', function(e) { $(this).remove(); });`

Comment: Please update the code with a [mcve]. You are missing at least one more image to show us what you mean - update the snippet with the code you need as well

Comment: what about a page with working code?

Comment: I cannot fix your code. You need to add the draggable if that is important to the issue at hand. This was not the file needed it seems: `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.19.1/utils/Draggable.min.js"></script>`

Comment: draggable is not important at this time all that matters is that individual images can be deleted on double click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You registered the double click event on main container.
If you want to delete the images when they double clicked, this should be work.

`$(".bananas").on('dblclick', '.modal-content', function(e) { 
    $(this).remove(); 
});`